# Setting a global variable before navigating

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm setting a global variable to null before navigating to the mainpage and in the mainpage I check to see if that variable is null of not, but It isn't.

It seems to be behaving correctly when I slow down the execution using breakpoints.

Otherwise Doing a

`NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));`

straight after setting something in app just makes that not work.

Are there any considerations that I am missing, because I fear that the issue could be anywhere in the app (i've looked for anything that sets it back, and there's also nothing running in between Navigate and it landing on MainPage

Comment: How and where a global variable is declared? How do you set it? Code part would increase the possibility of a good answer.

Comment: I suspect it's a race condition due to setting the global variable in a different thread. To be able to help further we'll need to see your code.

Comment: i think it might be due to using nonlinearnavigation and doing something in the onnavigatedto of the previous page. as a work around I created a new variable to tell the mainpage to do the setting to null instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using on the mainPage, OnNavigatedFrom page event and under that change the value to Null. Also Handle your app with [Tombstoning](http://imaginativeuniversal.com/blog/post/2010/08/22/WP7-Tombstoning-Pattern-Tip.aspx) appropriately and back up persistent Data, Even have it load that Persistent Data when you navigate to a new page and then check to make sure that valued reference is Null.

I do hope this helps you, i have recently had an issue similar.